# Deploy Strapi and MongoDB to a server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, strapi

We have no clue about deployment of a react app that is currently running with strapi and a mongoDB.
The Problem is that me and my colleague can't see each others changes in the DB without importing the data files manually everytime.
We would like to be able to access the Strapi CMS from our server and store all the data in a shared DB. That way the customer does not need to open the code whenever he wants to change something.

We would like to avoid heroku and aws and deploy it on our own server.
Where should we start?

## ps. We are Frontend guys!

Answer (score 0):

For the database, you can use MongoDB Atlas.

Like this, you can have one database (hosted) for your development environment.
Here how to start with Strapi + MongoDB Atlas - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html#mongodb-installation